# Неправильная работа column-count

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть страница

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 370px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.level1 {
  border: 1px solid thistle;
}

ul.level1>li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid thistle;
}

ul.level1>li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.level2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 559px;
  height: 1010px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid thistle;
  visibility: hidden;
  column-count: 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.level2>li {
  padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.level2>li>ul>li {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 0;
}

ul.level1>li:hover ul.level2 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu a {
  color: #333;
}

.alignblock {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.submenutitle {
    color: black;
    font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.submenuitem {
    color: gray;
    font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

</style>    
<!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Настройка viewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body>
        <div class="mainwrap">
            <div class="mainmenu">
                <span>
                    <span>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu" class="hamburger animated fadeInLeft noclose is-open" type="button">
                        <span class="hamb-top"></span>
                        <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
                        <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                    <span><div class="label menu-label" id="myelement">КАТАЛОГ ТОВАРОВ</div></span>
                    </span> 
            
            <nav class="menu">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li id="l1">
      <div class="alignblock">Бытовая техника для кухни</div>
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenutitle">
                            Крупная бытовая техника
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Холодильники
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Морозильные камеры
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Морозильные лари
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Плиты газовые
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 2</div>
    </li>
    <li id="l3">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 3 +</div>
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>Sub-Item 3-1</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-2</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-3</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-4</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-5</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-6</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-7</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 4-8</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 4</div>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 5</div>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 6</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
            
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
          <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

В таком случае отображение имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же в коде стоит

```html
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenutitle">
                            Крупная бытовая техника
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <br/>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Холодильники
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Морозильные камеры
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Морозильные лари
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Плиты газовые
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

то отображение имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Как добиться отображения всех пунктов меню в одну колонку (с пустой строкой после Крупная бытовая техника)?
2. И почему такая разница в отображении двух вышеприведенных вариантов кода? Почему во втором случае пункты меню Крупная бытовая техника, Холодильники, Морозильные камеры и т.д. не отображаются, как и в первом случае в одну колонку (воздействие каких операторов оказало влияние на внешний вид, но не только `<br/>`)?

Comment: Так а что вы хотите? Вы сами высоту внутреннему блоку со списком задали. Он доходит до низу и строит рядом. Уберете высоту - будет всё как надо.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar если убрать height: 1010px, то отображается как в первом случае

Comment: @Sevastopol' `level2` является подуровнем `level1`, в первом примере я заменил одну модификацию `level2`  другой модификацией `level2` (вместе с `<br/>`)

Comment: @Sevastopol' и почему если `<br/>` имеет влияние на внешний вид, то почему `column-count` отработало неправильно.